# If all Sylow subgroups of $G$ intersect in Sylow subgroups of solvable subgroup $H$, then $H$ is subnormal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $H \le G$ be a solvable subgroup of the finite group $G$ such that for each prime $p$ and each Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$ of $G$ we have
>   $$
>  S \cap H \in \mbox{Syl}_p(H).
> $$
>   Then $H$ is subnormal in $G$, i.e. there exists a sequence of subgroups $H \unlhd A_1 \unlhd A_2 \unlhd \ldots \unlhd A_n \unlhd G$.

I tried to suppose that $H$ is not subnormal and we have $H < G$ with $N_G(H) = H$ (by going over to factor groups this poses no real restriction), but I have no idea how to proceed. As $H < G$ I guess there must be some $S \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ such that $H \cap S$ is properly contained in $S$, then I know that $H \cap S < N_G(H\cap S) \le S$, maybe that helps. Also if $p$ divides the order of $H$, then each $S \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ has non-trivial intersection with $H$ by hypothesis.

Also note that in each finite group $G$ with subgroup $H$ we have for $P \in \mbox{Syl}_p(H)$ some $S \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ such that $P = H \cap S$, so the above is the converse assumption to this statement.

So any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: A minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $H$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$. Then $N$ is contained in every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ and hence in every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, so $N \le O_p(G)$. By induction applied to $G/O_p(G)$, $HO_p(G)$ is subnormal in $G$, so that reduces it to proving that $H$ is subnormal in $HO_p(G)$. Maybe you can take it rom there?

Comment: If $HO_p(G) < G$, then we can reason inductively as well. For if $S \in \mbox{Syl}_p(HO_p(G))$, then there exists $P \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ with $S = HO_p(G) \cap P$ and by assumption $P \cap H \in \mbox{Syl}_p(H)$. But $S \cap H = (HO_p(G) \cap P) \cap H = (HO_p(G) \cap H)\cap P) = H\cap P$, so that the assumption is fulfilled for $H$ and $HO_p(G)$ and $H$ is subnormal in $HO_p(G)$. The case $HO_p(G) = G$ I do not see yet, is it difficult?

Comment: When $HO_p(G)=G$, all Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$ for $q \ne p$ lie in $H$, and they generate a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ of index a power of $p$ with $K \le H$.